# A function using parameters but not included in declaration?

Tags: javascript, function

I was just wondering if it was possible to write a function in JavaScript without having any parameters in declaration parentheses but actually using them inside. For example in below, the function would give me 10 but if I want to change my parameter number to 5 and want to calculate sumThem(1,2,3,4,5); this function should give me 15 as result.

```
function sumThem() { //No parameters will be this line
  //let result = some magic will be in these lines... result become sum of all parameters.

  return result;

}

console.log(sumThem(1)); // should be 1
console.log(sumThem(1,2,3,4)); // should be 10
console.log(sumThem(1,2,3,4,5)); // should be 15
```

Comment: [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: In ES6 you can declare a spread parameter as `function sumThem(...paramName)`